# What Is The Fulfillment Of Numbers 24:24?

Tags: assyria, numbers

And ships shall come from the coast of Chittim, and shall afflict Asshur, and shall afflict Eber, and he also shall perish for ever.(Numbers 24:24)

There are many different interpretations to Numbers 24:24 and is often a text that has a variety of answers like for example, some say this is dealing with the sea peoples who invaded the Levant in the 13th century BC who afflicted the Hebrews and the other people in the Levant. Others say this is dealing with Greece conquering the lands of Assyria and oppressing the Jews. What is the proper and historic interpretation to Numbers 24:24?

Comment: Like many of the promises/prophecies in the bible, there is debate about the proper fulfillment and it's not clear what it is. The bible rarely says when a prophecy is fulfilled.

Comment: Prophecy fulfilment questions usually aren't on-topic here as there are too many possible answers. No one can prove what the intended referent is, so you'll just have to ask Moses or God if you ever get the chance to meet them!